# codeIgniter use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.database connection issue

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, mamp

I have code igniter installed on server with database I want to run the same db on my mac, I used MAMP and I copy the project folder inside htdocs, but I have this error
would you please help me!

```
ErrorException [ 8192 ]: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.
```

Comment: Do you use that function anywhere within your code? What you've posted here isn't relevant.

Comment: @tadman I update the question, actually I am new on this topic I have to run the project I got this error

Comment: It looks like it's falling back to some kind of compatibility mode because it can't find `mysqli`. Which modules does it have loaded? You can usually find out with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

Comment: @tadman I did not get how to find it

Comment: as an aside, it may help you to have a config/staging and config/development folder in which you add your customised database.php file.  common databases can then be included from the config/database.php file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't be afraid to change core files, just alter FCPATH/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

```
function escape_str($str, $like = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($str))
    {
        foreach ($str as $key => $val)
        {
            $str[$key] = $this->escape_str($val, $like);
        }

        return $str;
    }

    if (function_exists('mysqli_real_escape_string') AND is_object($this->conn_id))
    {
        $str = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conn_id, $str);
    }
    else
    {
        $str = addslashes($str);
    }

    // escape LIKE condition wildcards
    if ($like === TRUE)
    {
        $str = str_replace(array('%', '_'), array('\\%', '\\_'), $str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

I had the same issue

---

Better solution -> https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/228288/ `"stated in github that it will be fixed in CodeIgniter 3.0 the fix already exists in that repository"`

Comment: [CodeIgniter 2.2.0](https://ellislab.com/blog/entry/codeigniter-2.2.0-released) was released in June of this year. The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/) has lots of activity. Maybe it's dead to you, but it's not dead.

Comment: How do you set the ENVIRONMENT constant (in index.php)?

Comment: @Gervs For a dead platform, it's amazing that 3.0 is in beta and will be fully released later this year. FYI, modifying the `core` files is never the way to go. A.) there's probably a supported update when you encounter such issues (as there is here). B.) it's the whole reason behind the folders in the `application` directory. You make extended modifications there and incorporate.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
function escapeString($val) {
    $db = get_instance()->db->conn_id;
    $val = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $val);
    return $val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$db['development']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['development']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';

$db['staging']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['staging']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
```

I have update the answer

Comment: then I have this error, PDOException [ 1049 ]: SQLSTATE[42000] [1049] Unknown database 'bmgr1'

Comment: `copying the project folder inside htdocs` to your machine almost certainly didn't bring the MySQL database with it; you will need to export the database from the production machine, and then import it into your local MySQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

also, to use the function mysqli_real_escape_str, you need the mysqli , to get it

```
function get_mysqli() { 
$db = (array)get_instance()->db;
return mysqli_connect('localhost', $db['username'], $db['password'], $db['database']);}
```

The above function returns a mysqli object such that you can use,

```
$escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string(get_mysqli(),$string);
```

It works well, not so important here though!

Answer (score 0):

It's not goot idea edit core CI files. If you don't want see deprecated warnings from `mysql_escape_string`, to use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead you need open connection with DB. Use `db->initialise()` in your base controller

```
class Base_controller extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
     parent::__construct();

    $this->load->database('db_name');
    $this->db->initialize();
```

Answer (score -3):

make a function in Model class which will use database connection string and pass the value from controller to convert it with mysqli_real_escape_string()

```
function MysqliRealeScapeString($val){

    $new = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->conn_id, $val);
    return $new;
}
```