# mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-3

This is some strange problem I'm facing, my local machine runs php 5.6.3 while live server is running php 5.4. We recently updated our app from codeigniter 2.* to codeingiter 3.0, now while running on live server we came to know about this brand new issue (older one and still not working [smtp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482020/smtp-not-working-in-ci-3-0-while-same-code-is-working-in-ci-2))

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead.
>
> Filename: mysql/mysql_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 319

Now after doing some googling, I found that top solution [might be for ci 2.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169455/codeigniter-use-mysql-real-escape-string-instead-database-connection-issue) doesn't work as codeigniter's `mysql_drivers.php` file is already using `mysql_real_escape_string()`. One answer is suggesting that I should check `database.php` file. If my default connection is `mysql` instead of `mysqli` which is `mysqli`, now I've no way to find out what is going wrong or what I'm missing.

Comment: Consider using prepared statements and you don't need to use `mysql_escape_string()` or `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1):

PHP `mysql` driver is deprecated since 5.5.
See http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

So you better not use it. Use `mysqli`.

Line 319 on `mysql/mysql_driver.php`:
https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3fe79499c5bedb5b3bc4281821776f031f73674e/system/database/drivers/mysql/mysql_driver.php#L319

There is no `mysql_escape_string()`. It seems you didn't update to 3.0 correctly.

Comment: yes even i saw, but i don't know why it is throwing this warning ? I updated CI thoroughly following the blog

Comment: What do you mean? Your `mysql/mysql_driver.php` code is different from 3.0's code, isn't it? 3.0's code line 319 is comment ` * Rollback Transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

And problem is **you are conflicting** [MySQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) and [MySQLi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi)

To solve your problem use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

### More Details to Your Knowledge

About `mysql_escape_string()`

> **Warning:**
>   This function was deprecated in PHP 4.3.0, and will be removed in the future, along with the entirety of the original MySQL extension. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   [`mysqli_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php)
>   [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)

About `mysql_real_escape_string()`

> **Warning:**
>   This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
>   [`PDO::quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php)